# Android: Interstitial Facebook ad error 100

Tags: android, facebook, interstitial

Android:  I'm trying to get Interstitial Ad  and have this error: 
(#100) Param REQUEST_TIME must be a number=-0

at

```
facebookInterstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, this.getString(R.string.facebook_id__interstitial));

facebookInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
    //here
```

Anyone can help?
The api error 100 is : Invalid parameter,  but dunno why

Comment: I have the same error now. You have found a solution?

Comment: Infortunaly I didnt

Comment: Same issue with native ads, only since yesterday has this been affecting me. Did they update and break it? If so can we move back?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug introduced in the latest Facebook Audience SDK version (4.17.0).
You can downgrade the version manually to prevent the bug and wait for Facebook to fix the bug.

To downgrade change:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+')
```

to

```
compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.16.1')
```

This is exactly why having dynamic dependencies (using `+`) is a bad idea. I'd recommend to always use a static version and upgrade manually with proper testing.

The available versions of the Facebook SDK can be found here: [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.facebook.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22audience-network-sdk%22)

Comment: Tried this with compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'), did not receive the error 1203, everything works fine. Maybe the project should be cleaned and rebuild after upgraded to new version of SDK.

Comment: Thanks. You solve my problem. Its really a bug.
I LOVE YOU.